# Symfony2 Doctrine skipping over a bundles Entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two bundles both under Site.. Any Entity i create in User is processed but any entity that is added to Core is skipped.. I moved all the Entities from User to Core and created a text Entity but know im getting an error:

```
No Metadata Classes to process.
```

The test class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Site\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Test
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_address_type")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Test", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $addressTypeId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address_description", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address_description;


}
```

My config is this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
                # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
                # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    SiteCoreBundle:  ~
                    SiteUserBundle: ~
```

I have searched all over the place with no answer to be found. The closet was about using multiple connections which is where the config came from.

Thanks..

Comment: Look under CoreBundle/Resources/config/doctrine and make sure you don't have any orm files hanging around.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks this kind of helped. There was a residual test.orm.yml file in the CoreBundle. I removed the file and added a doctrine directory to the Core and User bundle and everything is now working. Im unsure if it was the lack of that directory or the file itself.

Comment: It was the file.  You can use annotations or an orm file but not both.  If you have both then it fails silently.